# How to get all users by project on Youtrack rest api?

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I can't get users by project or by filter on YouTrack REST API;

I wrote the following code:

```
var login = "mylogin";
var password = "mypassword";

(async function getAllUserByProject(login, password, project) {
        var url = ``https://mycompany.myjetbrains.com/hub/api/rest/users?`;
        return new Promise((done, fail)=> {
            request.get({
                url, auth: {user: login, pass: password, sendImmediately: true}
            }, (error, body, result)=> {
                if (error || !result) {
                    return fail({
                        error: JSON.parse(error), result: result ? JSON.parse(result) : null
                    })
                }
                console.log(result)
                done(JSON.parse(result));
            })
        })
    }
)(login, password, project);
```

Comment: Which users do you want to get exactly? Project assignees, project team members, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but:

> users by project

Use `/rest/admin/user?project=<PROJECT_ID>`. I tested this on `v2017.3` and it works.

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/GET-Users.html

> by filter

As seen in the documentation, the resource url takes the form of `/rest/admin/user?{q}&{group}&{role}&{project}&{permission}&{onlineOnly}&{start}` where:

- `q` can be part of user login, name, or email
- `group` is the user's groupID
- `role` is the users's [role](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/GET-Roles.html)
- `project` see above
- `permission` is one of the user's [permissions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Get-All-Available-Permissions.html)
- `onlineOnly` get only users which are currently online
- `start` for pagination (page size fixed at `10`)

Answer (score 0):

As of YouTrack 2018.3, the [old REST API is becoming deprecated](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/deprecated-rest-api-reference.html) in favor of one that allows much more elaborate queries.

With the new API, you can use [`/hub/api/rest/projectteams/?$top=-1&fields=id`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/HUB-REST-API_Project-Teams_Get-All-Project-Teams.html) to get the full list of ids of all project teams, and, for each of those, [`/hub/api/rest/projectteams/{project id}/users`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/HUB-REST-API_Project-Teams_Users-of-Project-Team_Get-All-Users-of-a-Project-Team.html) to get the list of users in a given project team.